# Adding a view on top of a MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a MPMoviePlayerController that plays fullscreen. Then I want to add a UIButton above the movie, but it doesn't show up.

I have already tried inserting the view above the movie view like this:

```
mpc =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
[mpc setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];   

[self.view addSubview:mpc.view];
**[self.view insertSubview:self.backButton aboveSubview:mpc.view];**

[mpc setFullscreen:YES];

mpc.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

[mpc play];
```

And I have also tried adding the subview to the movie controller view, like I read in a similar question:

```
**[mpc.view addSubview:self.backButton];**
[self.view addSubview:mpc.view];
```

When I log the list of subviews I always get the button in the last position, after the MPMovieView and the MPSwipable view, but it doesn't show up.

EDIT:

I've been able to work it around by disabling `[mpc setFullscreen:YES]` and setting the frame of the movie's view to the bounds of the parent view and setting an aspect-fill scaling mode. Not the cleanest solution I guess, but it works for me.

```
mpc.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);

UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 500, 100, 100)];

myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

mpc.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
mpc.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;

[self.view addSubview:mpc.view];

[self.view addSubview:myButton];

[mpc prepareToPlay];
```

Comment: Your workaround is fine. However, you could have achieved the same by adding your controls when the player has switched over to fullscreen (detected by the respective notification).

Answer (score 3):

Add your button over the `MPMoviePlayerController` as you wrote:

```
[mpc.view addSubview:self.backButton]
```

Maybe your button is hidden or nil.
Try to set your player:

```
mpc.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
```

Anyway, I do it like this:

```
 MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
 mp.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
 UIButton *btnInfo = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:your_frame];
 [mp.view addSubview:btnInfo];
```

Anyway, don't use `[mpc play];` you better use `[mpc prepareToPlay];` (Performance issues)

Comment: You should never add anything directly onto the player's view (as written in the documents). Instead, add your controls onto the player's background view or onto the parent view of the player.

Comment: What if i want a button to appear when the movie play?!

Comment: MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen is not an option for me since I don't want any controls at all. I've tried all the above but nothing happens. I've found out that the problem is with:
`[mpc setFullscreen:YES]`
which "Determines if the movie is presented in the entire screen (obscuring all other application content)."