# Make a play button in center in MPMoviePlayerViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I'm working on the MPMoviePlayerViewController, I need to make a play button in the center to allow tap on this button, the video will start playing. I cannot find out the way to do that. Can you please give me any way to do it? It will be the same as the picture below:

[image]

Any suggestion should be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000905/adding-a-view-on-top-of-a-mpmovieplayercontroller

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide player controls if u don't want nativ controls, and implement custom.... U can add a button in Center of MPmovieplauercomtroller's view and use it to play and stop content In player....