# Customize DONE button in MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using **MPMoviePlayerViewController**. How do I change the **Done** button in the player toolbar as **Back button Icon**?

Answer (score 0):

look at this answer; I guess is the same think you want to achieve : 
[Adding a view on top of a MPMoviePlayerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000905/adding-a-view-on-top-of-a-mpmovieplayercontroller)